# Cross table with two datasets (one as the row and the other as the column)

Tags: birt

I have two datasets in my birt report :

1. Lesson (date)
2. Student (name)

and I would like to know how to create a cross table using the date (red) as the column names and name (blue) as the row names as shown below :

[image]

The cells will stay empty.

I have try to use the *Cross Tab* but it seems that I can only use one dataset.

*For information I am stuck with the version 2.5.2. I say this in case someone writes about a practical functionality available in the later version of birt... :-)*

Comment: Are both your datasets coming from the same, relational data source? If so, the simplest way is to cross join them in a single query, then use a pivot table from that query. Otherwise, a more complicated solution is possible.

Comment: @MarkBannister Yes, datasets are from the same data source. So if I understand, I have to create a new joint dataset, create a cross tab and use my new dataset columns as the data cube groups?

Comment: Yes, I think that would be the simplest solution.

Comment: @MarkBannister Ok, I'll try this solution. I'll give you a feedback on it if it works well or if I have more question. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @MarkBannister This works perfectly. Add your first comment as an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where both datasets are coming from the same relational data source, the simplest way to achieve this would normally be:

- Replace the existing two datasets with a single dataset, in which the two original datasets are cross-joined to each other;
- create a crosstab from the new dataset, with the new dataset columns as the data cube groups.